# How do I define a range object when I'm not in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, range, ms-project

I'm working on a VBA script in MS Project, which involves the creation of a workbook. But I'm doing something wrong when defining a range, and it seems like it works differently because I'm not in Excel.

This is my current code, boiled down to the problematic part:

```
Dim myExcel As Object
Dim myWb As Object
Dim myRange as Object 'Not sure if I should declare this one as an object or a range
Dim myRangeString as String

Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add

myRangeString = "$D$20, $C$23" 'For simplicity. Obviously this is not hard coded.

Set myRange = Range(myRangeString)
```

This code works fine in Excel. But in Project it stops and throws back "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.". Maybe that's because "Global" in this context is Project and not Excel. So I have tried different variations of MyExcel.Range(myRangeString), but then I get "Application-defined or object-defined error." instead.

Can anyone help?

Comment: For example, `Set myRange = myWb.Worksheets(1).Range(myRangeString)`. A range always has a parent worksheet, which in turn has a parent workbook. So, best to qualify them.

Comment: @BigBen I have tried that, but it also gives an "Application-defined..." error.

Comment: What is the actual `myRangeString` you're using?

Comment: It's quite a complicated nested for loop, and the resulting string depends on the situation. But the error is the same if I use the hard coded version I have in the example.

Comment: I don't have Project, but I can't reproduce this, using Word for example: `myRangeString = "$D$20, $C$23"`, `Set myRange = myWb.Worksheets(1).Range(myRangeString)` works without error. So something else is going on. The reason I asked about the actual `myRangeString` is that there's a 255-character limit if I remember correctly.

Comment: While testing it might be worth putting `myExcel.Visible = True` somewhere after you've defined it - can see what's going on in Excel then.

Comment: I would suggest you to add a reference to `Microsoft Excel x.x Object library` and declare the variable as they should be (`As Excel.Workbook`, `Excel.Worksheet` etc.). At least, temporarily. You will benefit of intellisense suggestions and see if a specific construction does not suggest anything.

Comment: @FaneDuru the references are in order. You mean I should change from this:
Dim myExcel as Object
Dim myWb As Object

To this?
Dim MyExcel as Excel.Application
Dim myWB As Excel.Workbook

Doesn't that kind of do the same thing as the two first"Set" lines?

Comment: Guys, I've solved it! Turns out that when I concatenate myRangeString in Project, I shouln't use comma between the cells, but semicolon. Don't ask me why!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved it more or less at the same as you posted your answers, @orange_guy and @Rachel. The solution was to use semicolon (not colon, and not comma). Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: What does `Debug.Print myExcel.International(5)` return?

Answer (score 0):

Just like @BigBen and @Darren, I don't have MS Project either, but I have a similar crossed-application VBA Script among Excel and Outlook and putting the "app" before worked quite well for me. Here's the snippet:

```
Public Sub XPTO()

Dim xExcelFile As String
Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xExcelRange As Excel.Range
   
'Get the dimension table
xExcelFile = "C:\path\toMyFile\File.xlsm"
Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
Set WKB = xExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
Set xExcelRange = xWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myTable").ListObject
```

So basically I mention the App before any variable. Also, one thing that might work is to **set** the variable you mentioned ("myRangeString") as an object. I don't know exactly why, but it happenned to work for me. So instead of:

```
myRangeString = "$D$20, $C$23"
```

You would put something alike:

```
set myRangeString = myWb.Sheet(1).Range("$D$20, $C$23")
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is using late binding which means that the objects are unknown until run-time and there is no [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense). The advantage to using late binding is that the code will run fine for users with older versions of Office. Otherwise it's preferable to user early binding. (See [Early and Late Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/).)

Use early binding by setting a reference to the Excel Object Library (in the VB Editor, Tools: References, scroll down and check the box for the Microsoft Excel Object Library)

Here's a working MS Project example of your code using **late binding**:

```
Sub ExportToExcelLateBindingCellByCell()

Dim myExcel As Object
Dim myWb As Object

Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myExcel.Visible = True
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add

myWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$D$20") = ActiveCell.Task.Name
myWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$C$23") = ActiveCell.Task.ID

End Sub
```

Writing to Excel in chunks using arrays is a great idea--perhaps that's what was intended by "$D$20, $C$23". However, the correct range syntax would be to use a colon, but D20:C23 is awkward, use C20:D23 instead.

Here is an **early binding** example that writes data in chunks, which is noticeably faster for large amounts of data.

```
Sub ExportToExcelEarlyBindingArray()

Dim myExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWb As Excel.Workbook

Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myExcel.Visible = True
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add

Dim TaskInfo(4, 2) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
    TaskInfo(i - 1, 0) = ActiveProject.Tasks(i).ID
    TaskInfo(i - 1, 1) = ActiveProject.Tasks(i).Name
Next i

myWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$D$20:$C$23") = TaskInfo

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Range` can accept both `$D$20,$C$23` and `D20:C23`, but they don't mean the same thing. The first consists of two cells, the second has eight.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but you can't read or write directly to a range like that since it has two areas, so why bother when it's still two writes? I think the OP intended an array.